# Monkeyrunner throwing "ShellCommandUnrespo​nsiveException" - any work around?

Tags: adb, python-2.7, monkeyrunner, android-sdk-1.6, jython-2.5

I am facing some issues in `device.shell('ping -c 2 192.168.1.1')` inside a monkeyrunner script.
Its throwing

```
ShellCommandUnrespo‌​nsiveException 
[main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnrespo‌​nsiveException
```

```
while (count<1000) :
device.shell('dmesg -c')
print '****swithing OFF wifi in loop NO-',count
device.touch(400,155,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
time.sleep(10)
print '****switching ON wifi in loop NO-',count
device.touch(400,155,MonkeyDevice.DOWN_AND_UP)
time.sleep(25)
fd=open('pingstats.txt','a+b')
fd.write('***Loop-%i \n************\n%s\n****************\n' % (int(count),ping))
ping = device.shell('ping -c 2 192.168.1.1')
status=re.search('unreachable',ping)
if status:
    dmesg=device.shell('dmesg')
    fd.write(logcat)
fd.close()
count = count + 1
```

Please see above script. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

your ping waits to long

add a -t

start with -t 1

Answer (score 0):

Just add `-t` . An example below works perfectly !

```
device.shell('pm enable packageName -t 15')
```